# what is the difference between cur.execute and con.execute?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In python manual :https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html.

In some code is :cur.execute(sqlite command),in some code is : con.execute(sqlite command),

what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `connection` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection)):

> execute(sql[, parameters]) This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates
>   an intermediate cursor object by calling the cursor method, then calls
>   the cursor’s execute method with the parameters given.

So to answer your question: It just creates a new cursor and executes your statement with this new cursor.